# QGIS and Ubuntu 'browse' dialogue causing crashing

Tags: qgis, ubuntu, gui

Below is an image of 'the suspect dialogue' in Ubuntu that when you encounter it in QGIS  you are most definitely going to crash the application.

http://ow.ly/i/ZGNc/original

You find this particular dialogue - which doesn't appear with every menu - when you use:
-  polygon centroids
- raster extraction / projection
- create new shapefile (from desktop when you browse to location of new file)

ubuntu 12.04
qgis 1.8

Comment: is that the correct link? (saving a shapefile?)

Comment: Yes - the image is of the dialogue box itself...

Comment: I have a ubuntu vm (oracle virtualbox) I cannot recreate this with QGIS - try reinstalling QGIS

Comment: I have the same issue on Ubuntu 12.04. I've also had file dialog problems with Scribus so I suspect it's a Qt issue rather than QGIS. Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: @Mapperz can you recreate if qt-at-spi is installed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution for me was to remove the `qt-at-spi` package. It can be removed via the Software Centre (search for qt-at-spi, and click the 'Remove' button), or using the following command from the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get remove qt-at-spi
```

(Reference for solution: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/qt-at-spi/+bug/973332)

This will affect accessibility functionality, so if that is important to you, this solution is not recommended.